# How can I list all users of the same location using the Github API?

Tags: github

It is my first time using the Github API, sorry if this is a stupid question. I did a short search for location:Germany, and got 39,063 users. I want to create a list of all the 39,063 usernames and tried this command:

`curl -i https://api.github.com/search/users?q=location%3AGermany | grep login`

However this returns only 30 hits.. Could anyone give me some advice, or guide me to the right resources?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to make additional requests for other [pages](https://developer.github.com/v3/#pagination):

> ### Pagination
>
> Requests that return multiple items will be paginated to 30 items by default. You can specify further pages with the `?page` parameter. For some resources, you can also set a custom page size up to 100 with the `?per_page` parameter. Note that for technical reasons not all endpoints respect the `?per_page` parameter, see [events](https://developer.github.com/v3/activity/events/) for example.
>
> ```
> $ curl 'https://api.github.com/user/repos?page=2&per_page=100'
> ```
>
> Note that page numbering is 1-based and that omitting the `?page` parameter will return the first page.
>
> For more information on pagination, check out our guide on [Traversing with Pagination](https://developer.github.com/guides/traversing-with-pagination).